# Openshift: 504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time

Tags: openshift, http-status-code-504

I'm reading the solutions. Most of them has a wrong database configuration.
My database is from AWS (RDS).

My application works at localhost jboss as 7 on my pc very well. But if i'm trying to login on openshift server, i'm getting the following error.

504 Gateway Time-out
The server didn't respond in time.

I'm using a scalable app and the large gears.
I did an upgrade to silver plane, but can't find a support page to create support tickets.